# flask-admin imposes required attribute on relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

[flask-admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) marks [db.relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) fields of [model views](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#model-views) as required, so there is no way to add a record if the table to which relationship goes is empty.

Example:

```
class Type(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name         = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    area_id      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("area.id", onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False, index=True)
    description  = db.Column(db.Text)

class Area(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name         = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    description  = db.Column(db.Text)
    types = db.relationship('Type', backref='Area', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')
```

**types** field is required during creation of **area** record through flask-admin, but If **type** table is empty, there is no way to add any information to the database. flask-admin wouldn't allow to add anything to Area table because of [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#relationships-backref) to Type table which makes the field required, but there is nothing in Type table yet. flask-admin wouldn't allow to add anything to Area table as well, because the field **types** is required on the page.

I couldn't find anything on the subject. There are some topics discussing workarounds for many-to-many relationships, but this is the simplest one-to-many relationship which to my understanding should just work out of the box.

I figured out that if I add Type to inline_models under Area model then I will see a button "Add Types" on create Area page, but if the inline_model itself has a relationship then that wouldn't help either, because of the same reason.

```
class ModelViewArea(ModelView):
    inline_models = ( models.Type, )

admin.add_view(ModelViewProductArea (models.Area, db.session, name="Area",  category='Product'))
admin.add_view(ModelViewProductType (models.Type, db.session, name="Type",  category='Product'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that if a foreign key associated with the relationship has **nullable=False** then **flask-admin** marks the field as required in **flask-wtf**. Once I removed **nullable=False** from attributes of the foreign key of **Type** class, **flask-admin** stopped showing the field as required in both Type model view and Area model view.

However, as I removed nullable=False there was no more reason for ondelete="CASCADE" and cascade behavior on relationship. [Default cascade](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#unitofwork-cascades) suits better. The final code looks like:

```
class Type(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name         = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    area_id      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("area.id", onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='SET NULL'), index=True)
    description  = db.Column(db.Text)

class Area(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name         = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    description  = db.Column(db.Text)
    types = db.relationship('Type', backref='Area', lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in git master. Flask-Admin 1.0.7 is a few months old already and the git version has accumulated quite a few changes since then.

Sergey's answer of removing `nullable=False` from the foreign key changes the semantics and is therefore a workaround. With Flask-Admin from master, the `nullable=False` can be left in.